# View is a search result

Tags: lotus, lotus-notes

Is there a way to determine that UI view show search results?
better to use LotusScript...

I just need to prevent users from doing specific actions to the documents selected in search results view.

Thanks

Comment: sorry mate - would like to help but don't really understand the question

Comment: Maybe a picture of what you have, and of what you want, would help us to understand what you want.

Comment: I think I understand what you are asking, but I am not sure. Let me try to state it here so you can confirm. You have a view, and you have some LotusScript code that runs in that view's context - perhaps as an action button. You want this code to be able to determine whether the view is displaying a search result, and only run if that is true. If the view is displaying the full set of documents, the code should not execute. Is this the correct interpretation of your problem?

Comment: exactly, Richard.. .But I want block code to run on search results and run it only on full set of documents.. but it's really doesn't matter... So how does code know that the view shows the search results?

Answer (score 1):

A view can not be programmatically set to only show search results. This task is usually achieved by using a "SPOFU"- Folder (Shared, Private on First use) and put the search results in there with your Code. There are a lot of things to consider when doing such code, therefor I only add a script snippet on how it would look:

```
Dim ses as New NotesSession
Dim db as NotesDatabase
Dim dc as NotesDocumentCollection

Set dc = db.FtSearch(...

Call dc.PutAllInfolder( "SearchResults" )
```

This code is not tested, and it does not provide a way to empty the folder before the search and to open the folder after successfull search, but it should give an idea...

Comment: OK, I don't need to do a search by LotusScript. User does it in UI ("View->Search This View"). Then I need by LotusScript determine that the current view shows the search results